# Set and restrict home directory win32-openssh on windows for sftp

Tags: windows, openssh

Installed Win32-OpenSSH on Windows 2008R2 server.
Using local users to login etc.
Two questions:
How do I set the home directory for

1. How do I set the home directory for users? It is currently set to c:\users\ and it is then also filled with all the clart that Windows creates for each user
   and
2. How do I restrict the user to only be in that folder so that they can't browse around the whole server uploading and viewing at will

All the guides that I can find talk about the etc/ folder and passwords files etc. But they are not there on win32-openssh.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

I think the win32-openssh build still does not have chroot support, and you would need to do a full cygwin install, then install the cygwin ssh server. Here is a great video that outlines that process-
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dL-9k4riBps

Comment: Ah... a YouTube.com video link only type of an answer I see. I know the YouTube links never go bad do they? Maybe needs converted to a comment perhaps instead.